# mypy: How to apply *args on a Callable type?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a function like below,

```
def run_the_f(f):
  # run f function after some validation
```

Based on some condition, the signature of f function changes like `f(1.0), f(1.0,2.0), f(1.0,2.0,3.0,..)`. In other words, the number of input arguments can be varying in f similar to [udf f in pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html).

I am using mypy and I tried below which is failing,

```
def run_the_f(f: Callable[[*float],float]):
  # run f after some validation
```

Can someone support in what to fill in the Callable?

Comment: Just to note, the `*` in something like `def f(*args): ...` is really part of the `def` statement syntax, not an operator you can apply to names in other contexts.

Answer (score 5):

Using `typing.Protocol`:

```
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar
from abc import abstractmethod

T_contra = TypeVar('T_contra', contravariant=True)
T_co = TypeVar('T_co', covariant=True)


class SupportsCallWithArgs(Protocol[T_contra, T_co]):

    @abstractmethod
    def __call__(self, *args: T_contra) -> T_co:
        pass


def run_the_f(f: SupportsCallWithArgs[float, float]):
    f(1., 2., 3.)   # pass
    f([])           # fail: Argument to "__call__" of "SupportsCallWithArgs" has incompatible type "List[<nothing>]";
                    # expected "float"

def f(*args: float) -> float:
    pass


run_the_f(f)             # pass
run_the_f(lambda: None)  # fail: Argument 1 to "run_the_f" has incompatible type "Callable[[], None]";
                         # expected "SupportsCallWithArgs[float, float]"
```

`VarArg` in mypy's expansion package maybe a simpler choice (according to the reference provided in the comment area, this choice is **not recommended**):

```
from collections.abc import Callable
from mypy_extensions import VarArg


def run_the_f(f: Callable[[VarArg(float)], float]):
    f(1., 2., 3.)    # pass
```

But this seems to be just mypy's *self hypnosis*, Pycharm's type checker will prompt `2.` and `3.` as unexpected arguments of `f`:

```
# mypy_extensions.py
def VarArg(type=Any):
    """A *args-style variadic positional argument"""
    return type
```

Comment: Hi I am getting `Argument 1 to "run_the_f" of "MyClass" has incompatible type "Callable[[float, float], float]"; expected "SupportsCallWithArgs[float, float]"` when I define my function as `def product(a:float, b:float) -> float: return a*b`

Comment: @Selva Because `product` can't accept variable parameters, which is inconsistent with your problem description...

Comment: `VarArg` is not just mypy-only, but highly discouraged and considered deprecated, here's [the reference](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/additional_features.html#extended-callable-types).

Comment: @SUTerliakov Thanks for providing reference. This is something I found through mypy's tips. It has not been investigated in detail.